# Java: How to get the index of the maximum element in an integer ArrayList?

Tags: java

I read about the indexOf and .max methods and tried to do this

```
int indexOfMax =list.indexOf(Collections.max(list));
```

But I get a NoSuchElementException. How else could one go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your list is empty.
According to the docs the mentioned exception happens when the collection is empty